# Perl Matching Part of String

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to grab the date portion out of file paths so I may use them in a file name. For example, the files may be of the format:

```
$file1 = "/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my.text"  
$file2 = "/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my.text"  
$file3 = "/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week50c-ERT-lk-my.text"
```

Regardless of the file name formats from above, there is a portion in there that has the format "79weekxxX" where xx is a week number and X is a letter. I want to grab the portion "weekxxX" from each of these string names in order to create a final file name with just this string. For example, if my file is `$file1`, then I would like to store it in another variable such as week which contains `week48a` and create another variable just called `$filename="$week.txt"`.

I'm thinking regex matching can be used to do this but I'm not quite sure how. Please let me know if any part of my question remains unclear so that I may further elaborate. Thank you.

Edit:
The "79week" is always there. To be exact, I will not be accessing them as variables with file names. The paths are values of a nested hash for its own corresponding keys. So would it work to do something like:

```
 my %hash = ( 
        "rev" => {
            "first" => "$filepath1",  
            "second" => "$filepath2", 
            "third" => "$filepath3"                      
        },  
        "for" => {
            "first" => "$filepath1_2",  
            "second" => "$filepath2_2", 
            "third" => "$filepath3_2" 
        }   
    );

foreach my $inner (keys %{$hash{$outer}}){
my $file = basename($inner); //only takes the file name, and ignores the rest of the path
my ($week) = $file =~ /79week(\d\d)([a-zA-Z])/;
$filename = "$week.txt";
}
```

Comment: Is the `79` and `week` always there? If so, fairly easy to do `/79week(\d\d)([a-zA-Z])/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8OR9NA/1/)

Comment: @dawg please check post edit

Comment: `my ($week) = $file1 =~ /-[0-9]{2}(week[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z])-/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Observation:**

If `$file` contains a string such as:

`/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my.text`,

then if you execute:

`$file  =~ /79(week\d+[a-z])/i;`

variable `$1`, which is set to the Group 1 match from the above regex, will contain (in the above example):

`week48a`

You can then assign `my $week = $1;`

I hope that answers you Regex-related question.

Your statement:

`my ($week) = $file =~ /79week(\d\d)([a-zA-Z])/;`

will only set `$week` to Group 1, or `48`. So the other alternative, would be:

`my ($week) = $file =~ /79(week\d\d[a-zA-Z])/;`