# Using Regex to match pattern and store into array

Tags: regex, perl

I had a similar post on this (see [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439561/perl-matching-part-of-string)), but what I am trying to do has slightly varied since then. I am using the same regex matching `/79(week\d+[a-z])/i` from that question.

I have a file that contains six lines, each line a different path. As an example, there are 3 lines including the string "cat" and 3 lines including the string "dog".

file.txt

```
/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my_cat.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my_cat.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week50c-ERT-lk-my_cat.text 
/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my_dog.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my_dog.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week49b-ERT-lk-my_dog.text
```

I want to take the "weekxxX" portion out of each path and print it out into a file. Here is what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

    open (my $fh, '<', "file.txt") or die "Couldn't open `file.txt`\n";

    foreach my $line (<$fh>){ #goes through each line in the file

        chomp $line; #chomps new line character from each line

        if ($line =~ /cat/) { #if the path includes string "cat"
            #use the regex at top of post to get weekxxX of each
            #path containing cat and print all 3 weekxxX into 
            #another file called cat.  

            open (my $cat, '>', "cat.txt") or die;
            print $cat "";
            close $cat; 

        }
        elsif ($line =~ /dog/) { #otherwise if the path includes string "dog"3

            #use the regex at top of post to get weekxxX of each
            #path containing cat and print all 3 weekxxX into 
            #another file called dog.  

            open (my $dog, '>', "dog.txt") or die;
            print $dog "";
            close $dog;
        }
    }
    close $fh;
```

I am thinking this can be done by using regex on all three paths (depending on whether it is dog or cat), push all three weeks in format weekxxX into an array and then print that array into the file? I'm really not sure how to implement this.

Comment: `cat.txt` and `dog.txt` need to be in quotes.

Comment: You're never printing `$line` into the files. You also need to open the files in append mode, so you don't overwrite the previous lines.

Comment: @Barmar i dont want to print the lines themselves into the files.

Comment: Then use a regexp that extracts the portion of the line you want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444009/how-can-i-extract-substrings-from-a-string-in-perl for how to extract substrings.

Comment: @Barmar it's not that straightforward for me. If I were not having issues, I clearly wouldn't have posted the question. Please read the entire post to understand what I am wanting to do exactly and where I am having trouble.

Comment: Did you read that question, it shows exactly how to extract the `weekXXX` part of the line into a variable. Then push the variable onto a list `@cats` or `@dogs`.

Comment: I am not sure I get it ... do you want two output files, `cat.txt` and `dog.txt`, where each will have that `weekNNa` pattern from corresponding lines?

Comment: @Barmar no, i just saw your comment with the link. I will take a look at it now.

Comment: @zdim yes, that's right :)

Comment: @Barmar I never asked for someone to code it for me. I am looking for a helpful reply with some tips and insight on how to go about it as I don't know how to approach it. Comment sections are not made for prolonged discussions unrelated to clarification, so if you have any tips, i would appreciate it. Meanwhile, I will go ahead and just out the link you commented.

Comment: `if ($line =~ /(week...).*cat/) { push @cats, $1; }`

Comment: Your previous question is about how to extract the `weekXXX` part of the string, just like the question I linked to. It's not clear what more you need to know.

Comment: @Barmar my biggest confusion is getting it into an array for all three paths. I took a look at the other link, but still a bit confused. each time I fall into the if statement, i want to push the next weekxxX into the array so I end up with 3 weekxxX. I will give it a shot using my regex with `if ($line =~ /(week...).*cat/) { push @cats, $1; }` as you suggested.

Comment: When `open` fails you need to always print the error in `die`, for what the [`$!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) is there. It's commonly done like `open ... or die "Can't open $file: $!";`

Comment: @zdim i generally don't include it in my scripts because when i run perl scripts on my system, it will automatically give me the fail reason when dying (i include `use autodie` in my scripts)

Comment: OK, `autodie` does that (what I incidentally used in my answer here while I normally don't).  But then you don't need `or die` at all -- which is why I commented, seeing `die` without `$!`. I'd suggest to include that `use autodie;` in your code here (I'd comment if there weren't `die` at all, too :), along with `warnings` and `strict` -- you'll invariably get comments when they're missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

open(my $in_fh, '<', "file.txt")
   or die("Can't open \"file.txt\": $!\n");    
open(my $cat_fh, '>', "cat.txt")
   or die("Can't create \"cat.txt\": $!\n");
open(my $dog_fh, '>', "dog.txt")
   or die("Can't create \"dog.txt\": $!\n");

while (<$in_fh>) {
   chomp;
   if ( my ($week) = /79(week\d+[a-z])/i) {
      if    (/cat/) { say $cat_fh $week; }
      elsif (/dog/) { say $dog_fh $week; }
   }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer :) My question was finding a way to use the regex in the simplest way possible and this was straight to the point! kudos to @zdim for the mapping method, as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use autodie qw(open);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";  #/

# Patterns that determine what file to write to    
my ($p1, $p2) = qw(cat dog);

# Open output files, one for each pattern
my %fh_out = map { open my $fh, '>', "$_.txt"; $_ => $fh } ($p1, $p2); 

open my $fh, '<', $file;

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( my ($week, $type) = /79(week\d+[a-z]).*?($p1|$p2)/i ) {
        say {$fh{$type}} $week;
    }
}
```

Comment: really `my ($p1, $p2) = map { my $q = quotemeta; qr/$q/ } qw(cat dog);`

Answer (score 1):

Following code does what you are looking for

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

# define match pattern
my $patern = qr/\d{2}(week\d{2}\w).+(cat|dog)/;

my %hash;                               # define hash to store data

while( <DATA> ) {                       # read from DATA block
    next if /^$/;                       # skip empty lines
    chomp;                              # trim newline

    push @{$hash{$2}},$1 if /$patern/;  # fill the hash if match pattern
}

say Dumper(\%hash) if $debug;           # look into hash in debug mode

while( my($k,$v) = each %hash ) {       # go through hash
    my $filename = $k . '.txt';         # define filename

    open FH, "> $filename"              # open file
            or die "Couldn't open $filename";
    print FH join "\n", sort @{$v};     # print data into a file
    close FH;                           # close file
}

__DATA__
/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my_cat.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my_cat.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week50c-ERT-lk-my_cat.text 
/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my_dog.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my_dog.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week49b-ERT-lk-my_dog.text
```

**OUTPUT**

cat.txt

```
week46d
week48a
week50c
```

dog.txt

```
week46d
week48a
week49b
```

You need to start read some **Perl programming** [books](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/index.htm)

Comment: @ikegami please look into the code once more - it opens files 'cat.txt' and 'dog.txt' only once each (once for each hash key).

Comment: Use of bareword as filehandle is strongly discouraged, [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 0):

Code with utilization of **map** simplifies the code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

# define match pattern
my $patern = qr/\d{2}(week\d{2}\w).+(cat|dog)/;

my %hash;                               # define hash to store data

# fill the hash if match pattern
map { push @{$hash{$2}},$1 if /$patern/ } <DATA>;

say Dumper(\%hash) if $debug;           # look into hash in debug mode

foreach my $animal (keys %hash) {       # extract 'animal' from hash
    open FH, "> $animal.txt"            # open file
            or die "Couldn't open $animal.txt";
    map { say FH $_ } sort @{$hash{$animal}};       # print data into a file
    close FH;                           # close file
}

__DATA__
/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my_cat.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my_cat.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week50c-ERT-lk-my_cat.text 
/mypath/sd-urt7-dfc-adfj345h-d0-79week48a-DFC-lk-my_dog.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-afd-parent-79week46d-AFD-lk-my_dog.text  
/mypath/sd-urt7-ert-parent-79week49b-ERT-lk-my_dog.text
```